# mvc4 webgrid cell with form, code won't render <form> tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webgrid, html.beginform

I have a webgrid in MVC4, and I want a custom column to have submit buttons - to resend the message to a specific person.

The code of the column's format looks like this:

```
format: @<text>
@foreach (DataEntity entity in item.Entities)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("Resend", "Messages", new {MsgId = entity.MsgID }, FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <input Type="submit" value="@entity.PersonName" />
    }
}
</text>
```

This code was hand-copied from another PC, so ignore any apperant syntax errors.

My problem is that the HTML page doesnt have any form tags, although as you can see I AM using the Html.BeginForm...

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Thanks, Avi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html.BeginForm doesn't return a string, it writes directly to the page. This is why you don't get the form tags in the column contents.

The solution would be to write the  tags manually.

Edit:

```
<form action="/Messages/Resend" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="outgoingMsgId" value="@entity.MsgID" />
    <input type="submit" value="@entity.PersonName" />
</form>
```

Comment: So I did that, and I'm having a different problem - the method in the controller is named "public void Resend(int outgoingMsgId)", but I get an error saying that there's no such parameter...
How do I say to the asp.net mechanism that the form parameter is named "OutgoingMsgId" and not just "id"?

Comment: I've added an example of what should work. You might need to tweak it for your own source.